# Should I use 한복 or 치마 저고리?

Tags: word-choice

한복 is literally translated to English as "hanbok" and 치마 저고리 is literally translated to English as chima jeogori. And I recognise that 치마 저고리 is a subset of 한복 - all 치마 저고리 are 한복, but not all 한복 are 치마 저고리. And that men would wear 바지저고리.

If you wanted to say "she wore a hanbok", would you use 한복, or 치마 저고리?

I'm learning Korean for South Korea, not North Korea (which uses 조선옷 rather than 한복).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hanbok is a general term for Korean traditional costume and 치마 저고리 is specifically referring  basic female garments of 한복. Have a look at this picture:

http://danmee.chosun.com/wdata/photo/news/200412/20041210000040_09.gif

치마 is the skirt and 저고리 is the jacket.

I would say she wore a hanbok unless I have a special context to say 치마저고리 because almost always women wear 치마저고리. But it is also ok to say 치마저고리. It basically means "she wore a jacket and a skirt."

Comment: 치마 is a generic term for "skirt", but I think 저고리 is only used for a class of 한복.  Also, I'm not sure if it should be called "jacket", though there's probably not a good matching English term: see https://www.google.com/search?q=%EC%A0%80%EA%B3%A0%EB%A6%AC&tbm=isch